# How to echo SHOW TABLES query in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to display/ `echo` the `rows` if the query is:

```
<?php
    $query  = "SHOW TABLES FROM DB"
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc)
    {
        echo $row['Tables_in_DB']. "</br>";
    }
?>
```

I need to display all the rows of the tables

Comment: i've update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES FROM DB");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
        echo $row[0]. "</br>";
?>
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer: just change `fetch_assoc()` to `fetch_array()`